# Публикация приложения в Google Play для отдельных платформ

Tags: android, google-play

Можно ли в Google Play опубликовать 4 одинаковых приложения по одной для каждой платформы (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) ?

Дело в том, что приложение использует сторонние библиотеки, которые вместе весят больше чем само приложение. Поэтому хотелось бы их разделить, чтобы не заставлять пользователей качать лишние мегабайты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/filters.html#other-filters)
надо просто создать отдельный апк с либами под каждую отдельную платформу:

> Приложение, которое содержит специфичные библиотеки, предназначенные
>   для какой-то определенной процессорной архитектуры (например, ARM EABI
>   v7 или x86) видны только на устройствах, поддерживающих эту
>   архитектуру.

И ещё хотелось бы обратить внимание на то что у каждого из этих APK [должно быть разное versionCode](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#VersionCodes):

> Each APK for the same application must have a unique version code,
>   specified by the android:versionCode attribute. You must be careful
>   about assigning version codes when publishing multiple APKs, because
>   they must each be different, but in some cases, must or should be
>   defined in a specific order, based on the configurations that each APK
>   supports.

Думаю удобнее всего реализовать отдельные наборы библиотек и версий будет с помощью механизма Flavors, как то так:

```
android {
    ...

    def commonVersionCode = 10

    productFlavors {
        armeabi {
            versionCode commonVersionCode
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode commonVersionCode + 1
        }
    }
}
```

То есть основной номер версии держать кратным 10, а версии для конкретных платформ делать добавляя к основной 0, 1, 2 и т.д. Ну и библиотеки соответственно раскидать по папкам соответствующим flavor'ам.